# How can I add customized ggplot() legend for one especific geom_line()

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I plot this graph where the legend only shows the black geom_line only?

```
library(ggplot2)
# the data
x <- replicate(4, rnorm(100))
xmat <- matrix(x, ncol = 4, byrow = F)
m <- apply(xmat,1,mean)
m <- data.frame(cbind(value = m, Var1 = 1:100))
colnames(xmat) <- letters[1:4]
meltx <- as.data.frame(reshape2::melt(xmat))

# the plot
ggplot(data = meltx, aes(x=Var1, y = value, color = Var2)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_line(data = m, aes(x = Var1, y = value ), color = "black", size = 2) +
  theme(legend.position = "right")

# I want legend of black line only (data = m).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick and easy way to do this is to use the linetype aesthetic instead of the color aesthetic (if you only want a single line in the legend, the aesthetic you use to get the legend is not important, and this leaves the option of adding a separate color legend if desired)

```r
ggplot(data = meltx, aes(x=Var1, y = value, color = Var2)) +
  geom_line(show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_line(data = m, aes(x = Var1, y = value, linetype = "Your label here"), 
            color = "black", size = 2) +
  labs(linetype = NULL) +
  theme(legend.position = "right")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have a legend you have to map on aestehtics, i.e. move `color` inside `aes()` too, set your desired via `scale_color_manual` and finally set the `breaks` so that only the black line is displayed in the legend:

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(123)

pal_color <- scales::hue_pal()(dplyr::n_distinct(meltx$Var2))
names(pal_color) <- levels(factor(meltx$Var2))

pal_color <- c(pal_color, blackline = "black")
ggplot(data = meltx, aes(x = Var1, y = value, color = Var2)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_line(
    data = m, aes(x = Var1, y = value, color = "blackline"),
    linewidth = 2
  ) +
  scale_color_manual(values = pal_color, breaks = "blackline") +
  theme(legend.position = "right")
```

[image]